# python3 os path return value only root

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

i'm trying to set my workspace to current directory. but i tried so many things and it keeps return only root.

for example i used:

> from  pathlib import Path

> path.dirname(Path().absolute())

when i print it, it returns me

> Y:\

however, it should be

> Y:\Dev\

I tried different method such as using path from os , all it returns me the same thing. does anybody knows why this happens and how to deal with this? thanks

Comment: What is `Path.cwd()`? Instead of the os.path.dirname part, you could do `Path().absolute().parent` but that won't fix the current problem.

Comment: if `Path.cwd()` is `"Y:\\Dev"` then `os.path.join(Path.cwd(), 'main.ui')` is `"Y:\\Dev\\main.ui"`. If you are using pathlib, you don't also need os.path. You could do `Path.cwd()/"main.ui"` to get the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try this, it works for me:

```py
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
print(cwd)  # prints /path/to/original/dir
new_dir = cwd+'/dev' 
os.mkdir(new_dir)
os.chdir(new_dir)
print(os.getcwd())  # prints /path/to/original/dir/dev
```

Comment: seems you need to add /dev. but in case this code moves to github, others folder are not the same as mine. Funny things, i found that os.getcwd() returns Y:\Dev, but as soon as i os.path.join (os.getcwd(), 'file.ui') , it returns error Y:\\file.ui not found

Comment: If there is a bug, you don't just hard code data until it "works". Why not just hard code the full path value? The problem is that current working directory is different than OP thinks.

Comment: but if i push this code, others need to keep changing the path. you need to dynamically adjust this so everyone on the repository doesn't need to do any code changing @tdelaney

Comment: @YohanesLim - I was warning against this approach. Your code got the parent of the current working directory. If its not right, it means that current working directory is not right. That's why I asked you to print it. Did you want the parent of the .py file? That's different than CWD.

Comment: @tdelaney i was hoping i could get the working directory only. it return Y:\Dev. but as soon as i put it on os.path.join(Path.cwd(), 'main.ui') . it return me Y:\\main.ui

Comment: @KenMyers - I'm assuming Path is pathlib.Path and path.dirname is os.path.dirname.

Comment: We should move up to the question's comments. We are just spamming this answer at this point.

Comment: I don't mind, does this work for him:
```os.chdir(Path.joinpath(Path.cwd(),'dev'))
print(Path.cwd())```

Comment: If you want 'main.ui' in the current working directory, then `Path.cwd()/"main.ui"` does it.

Comment: thanks @tdelaney it does work! can you put the answer so i can vote it answer? thankss